# Weird varnish log output before crashing

Tags: varnish

Every once in a while, our varnish daemon stops responding and has to be restarted. Before I restart it, I dump the contents of the shared memory segment to disk using this command:

```
varnishlog -w /tmp/blah.log
```

When I take a look at the contents of the log later, it consists almost exclusively of lines that look like this (~1350 in total out of ~1380 lines):

```
0 WorkThread   - 0x48302cf0 start
```

Is there something that this is telling me? Previously we've had problems with bots bogging down the backend connections to Apache and causing similar hangs, but in this case, the Apache logs are clean.

Comment: It could be that it's telling you that it tries to fetch some object that's taking too long to fetch for instance. Other than that it's a bit hard to say anything based solely on that line.

Comment: @favoretti I think you're right. I think the varnish crashing is a symptom of the load on the machine skyrocketing due to another problem. Add this an as answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It could be that it's telling you that it tries to fetch some object that's taking too long to fetch for instance. Other than that it's a bit hard to say anything based solely on that line.

Adding as an answer as per request :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it could be a race condition in the varnish threads.

(since it's a daemon that uses IPC structures (shm) you can see if there's something weird going on with your shared memory with the 'ipcs' command)

Comment: Would you mind expanding on this a bit ?